# Is there an easy way to eliminate the final comma in my output? Number Seperator

Tags: java

For another assignment i needed to program a "number seperator", that splits any given int value into all of its digits and returns it to the main class as a String.

I have the program up and running but there's a small problem with my output.

```
public class NumberSeperator {

   static String splitNumber(int zahl)  {
       String s = Integer.toString(zahl);
       return s;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       System.out.println("Input a Number: ");
       int zahl = readInt();

       String ziffern = splitNumber(zahl);
       for (int i = 0; i < ziffern.length(); i++) {
           System.out.print(ziffern.charAt(i) + ",");
       }
   }
}
```

The output of 1234 should be: 1,2,3,4 
and the actual output is: 1,2,3,4,

At the risk of sounding extremely stupid, is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: Print the `,` in a separate statement after the character, and if `i` is the last number, don't print the comma.

Comment: another possibility is to only print the output after the iteration, and before you do substring(0, original.length-x) to get rid of those nasty last chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's the last iteration, just don't add it.

In the last iteration, it will make the `comma` empty so that you won't see it after the last value.

```
String comma=",";
for (int i = 0; i < ziffern.length(); i++) {
      if (i == ziffern.length()-1) {
         comma="";
       }
       System.out.print(ziffern.charAt(i) + comma);
 }
```

Comment: you welcome, @dvdxthl17 still not an answer though :P ?

Comment: there you go :D

Answer (score 3):

How about printing first element without comma and rest in form `,nextElement` like

```
one, two, three
^^^---------------- - before loop
   ^^^^^----------- - loop iteration
        ^^^^^^^---- - loop iteration
```

It can be achieved like:

```
if(ziffern.length()>0){
    System.out.print(ziffern.charAt(0));
}
for(int i=1; i<ziffern.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(", "+ziffern.charAt(i));
}
```

OR you can convert `ziffern` to `String[]` array first and use built-in solution which is: [`String.join(delimiter, data)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

```
System.our.print(String.join(",", ziffern.split("")));
```

Comment: That wont work because `ziffern` is a String not an array

Comment: Can't use these yet, I'm in my first semester and my professor likes to limit the tools we can use. Thank you nevertheless!

Comment: @Pshemo you need to add `""` to your split method. `.split()` doesn't have an empty method.

Answer (score 1):

with Java 8 and streams you can do it in a single command:

```
String join = Arrays.asList(ziffern.split(""))
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

System.out.println(join);
```

or with just plain java 8:

```
String join = String.join(",", ziffern.split(""));

System.out.println(join);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just output the string without the last character.
Your modified code should be:

```
public class NumberSeperator {

   static String splitNumber(int zahl)  {
   String s = Integer.toString(zahl);
   return s;
   }

public static void main(String args[]) {

           int zahl = 1234;
           String s="";
           String ziffern = splitNumber(zahl);
           for (int i = 0; i < ziffern.length(); i++) {
               s+=ziffern.charAt(i) + ",";
           }
           System.out.println(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite often this occurs when you know you have at least two items to print.  So here is how you could do it then.

```java
       String ziffern = splitNumber(zahl);
       String output = ziffern[0]; 
       for (int i = 1; i < ziffern.length(); i++) {
           output = "," + ziffern[i];
       }
       System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner will do your job:

```
static String splitNumber(int zahl)  {
    return String.join(",", String.valueOf(zahl).split(""));
}
```